# How to use EntityFramework CodeFirstStoreFunctions nuget package?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I am trying to access  an already existing function that is in my db. 
I want to execute this function from code first.

Searching the net i found:

https://codefirstfunctions.codeplex.com/

My implementation of this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<TrainMessage>()
        .Property(e => e.Latitude)
        .HasPrecision(18, 16);

    modelBuilder.Entity<TrainMessage>()
        .Property(e => e.Longitude)
        .HasPrecision(18, 16);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Stop>()
        .Property(e => e.stop_lat)
        .HasPrecision(18, 16);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Stop>()
        .Property(e => e.stop_lon)
        .HasPrecision(18, 16);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
        .Property(e => e.Latitude)
        .HasPrecision(18, 16);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
        .Property(e => e.Longitude)
        .HasPrecision(18, 16);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Subscription>()
        .Property(e => e.StartTime)
        .HasPrecision(0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Subscription>()
        .Property(e => e.EndTime)
        .HasPrecision(0);

    modelBuilder.Entity<OrderLocation>()
        .Property(e => e.Latitude)
        .HasPrecision(18, 16);

    modelBuilder.Entity<OrderLocation>()
        .Property(e => e.Longitude)
        .HasPrecision(18, 16);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
        .HasMany(e => e.OrderLocations)
        .WithOptional(e => e.Order)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.Order_Id);

    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionsConvention<TransitContext>("dbo"));
}

[DbFunction("TransitContext", "tvf_GetAllStopsInBetween")]
public IQueryable<int> GetAllStopsBetweenStations(int StopA_id, int StopB_id)
{
   var A = new ObjectParameter("StopA_id", StopA_id);
   var B = new ObjectParameter("StopB_id", StopB_id);

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext
        .CreateQuery<int>("[dbo.tvf_GetAllStopsInBetween](@StopA_id, StopB_id)", A, B);


}
```

It is not exactly what they show in the guide but I have a function in the db and they create it in the code so I figure I do not need the rest of the code.

I have two problems with this

**1)** No matter what data I am trying to get from the db I get:

> The argument 'name' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space.

**2)**
When I remove this part of the code:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionsConvention<TransitContext>("dbo"));
```

I get this:

> ErrorDescription = "'dbo.tvf_GetAllStopsInBetween' cannot be resolved
>   into a valid type or function."
>
> Message = "'dbo.tvf_GetAllStopsInBetween' cannot be resolved into a
>   valid type or function. Near escaped identifier, line 1, column 1."

I am fairly new to codefirst and I inherited this code.

How do i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

created a SP instead of a TVF and used the following code and problem was solved:

```
public ObjectResult<int> GetAllStopsBetweenStations(int StopA_id, int StopB_id)
{
    var A = new SqlParameter("StopA_id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    var B = new SqlParameter("StopB_id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);

    A.Value = StopA_id;
    B.Value = StopB_id;

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.
            ExecuteStoreQuery<int>("GetAllStopsInBetweenTest @StopA_id, @StopB_id ", A,B);
}
```

Comment: I was returning IQueryable<int> using CreateQuery and when I changed to the above pattern it worked for me.  I wasted a day on this, and this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I also got

> The argument 'name' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space.

when using the nuget package.

I cloned the codeplex repo and used the source directly and that error went away.
I think the nuget is actually out of date